# ¿Se pueden guardar los datos en otro lugar aparte de un back-end?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

¿Hay otro lugar para guardar los datos además de cookies, almacenamiento local y back-end?

Answer (score 2):

"Back-end" no es un lugar para almacenar datos, es solo un nombre para definir el software que se ejecuta en el lado del servidor (no disponible para el cliente).

Lo que hace este "software de back-end" depende de lo que el negocio y los desarrolladores hicieron que hiciera, ¿es un software para recibir y almacenar información en una base de datos? ¿Es un software solo para validar cosas y devolver verdadero o falso? Sea lo que sea, no es el almacenamiento de datos, sino un software que, si está programado para hacerlo, puede recibir sus datos y almacenarlos en una base de datos adecuada.

Los datos, se pueden almacenar básicamente en archivos o bases de datos. También hay memoria, pero no creo que sea eso lo que estás buscando)

Ahora debe definir DÓNDE desea que se guarden estos datos, ¿se pueden guardar en la máquina del cliente o es necesario guardarlos en el servidor? Eso es lo primero que tienes que definir.

Si desea guardarlo en la máquina del cliente, puede usar cookies, almacenamiento local, un archivo o algo más (hay algunos frameworks de javascript para trabajar con el almacenamiento de datos).

Si desea guardarlo en un servidor, debe crear un "software de back-end" para recibir primero esta información y luego almacenarla correctamente en una **base de datos** (postgres, MySQL, oracle, mariadb, ...) o en un **archivo** (csv, txt, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el localstorage (cliente), sessionstorage (cliente), bases de datos (server), puedes hacer que se guarde alguna informacion en archivos en el servidorcomo en archivos txt, json, xml,...